# Suggested tag synonym is not shown in the suggested filter when logged in

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tagging

I have suggested a tag synonym in https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/asking-questions/synonyms. The suggestion is shown as "pending (0)" in https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms:

[image: It is shown in the overview of tag synonym]

But if I filter for suggested tag synonyms https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested it is not shown, the list is empty. I just got another tag synonym accepted and it *was* shown in the suggested filter for tag synonyms so there seems to be some inconsistency. The strange thing is that it is *not* empty when I am logged out. Other Stack Exchange sites seems to behave the same. Is this a bug?

I am using Firefox 10.0.2 and I have tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh the page and it is still empty. I get the same behavior in Firefox 11.0 and Chromium 16.0.912.77 and 17.0.963.79. I have also tried to visit it in safe mode and it is still empty.

When I view the HTML source for the relevant table in https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested **logged in** I see the following:

```
<table id="synonyms-table">
    <thead>
    <tr>

        <th>Master<span class="fr arrow">&larr;</span></th>
        <th>Synonym</th>
        <th class="creator">Creator</th>
        <th class="rename-count">Renames</th>
        <th>Last</th>
        <th></th>

    </tr>
    </thead> 

</table>
```

When I view the HTML source for the same table **logged out** I see the following:

```
<table id="synonyms-table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Master<span class="fr arrow">&larr;</span></th>
        <th>Synonym</th>
        <th class="creator">Creator</th>
        <th class="rename-count">Renames</th>
        <th>Last</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead> 


<tr class="synonym-10">
    <td>
        <a href="/tags/asking-questions/synonyms" class="post-tag" title="synonyms for'asking-questions'" rel="tag">asking-questions</a> 
        <span class="">
            <span class="item-multiplier">&times;&nbsp;8</span>
        </span> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="/questions/tagged/questions" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged 'questions'" rel="tag">questions</a>
        <span class="dim">
            <span class="item-multiplier">&times;&nbsp;2</span>
        </span>
    </td>
    <td class="creator">
        <a href="/users/5701/n-n">N.N.</a> 
        <br> 
        <span title="2012-02-22 16:55:49Z" class="relativetime">1d ago</span>
    </td>
    <td class="rename-count">0</td>
    <td></td>

        <td class="pending">pending <span title="total score">(0)</span></td>
</tr></table>
```

This clearly shows why I do not see any contents in the table when logged in and why I see it when logged out. But why is this?

Comment: Did you refresh the page in your browser? I'm able to see the suggestion in the suggested filter.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz I even made a Ctrl+F5 and also tried to visit it in safe mode in Firefox 10.0.2 and it is still empty. The strange thing is that it is not empty when I view it in Chromium.

Comment: It's the same with Opera 11.61 (Windows 7): The proposal is shown in http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms, but not in http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested. However, with [Opera 12.00 alpha](http://de.opera.com/browser/next/), it works correctly.

Comment: @diabonas Good to know. Anyone with other browsers should report too.

Comment: Also not shown in FF 3.6.28 (the current 3.6 Legacy Firefox).

Answer (score 2):

I can't replicate your result in the current codebase, so I'm marking as norepro.